# Sms onReceive Intent Bundle

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

Everythings work normally but when i run my code i show the log window: No service

OK but;
i have an error because debugger say "tag" is null.Why?

onCreate;

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("ID", "MY ID NUMBER");

Intent sendintent   = new Intent(SENT);
sendintent.putExtras(bundle);

PendingIntent sentPI        = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, sendintent, 0);
```

onReceive;

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         String tag = intent.getExtras().getString("ID");
         Log.d("ID", tag); <<<NULL
         switch (getResultCode()) {
             case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                 Log.i("SmsSentReceiver", "SMS sent");
                 break;
             case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                 Log.i("SmsSentReceiver", "Generic failure");
                 break;
             case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                 Log.i("SmsSentReceiver", "No service");
                 break;
             case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                 Log.i("SmsSentReceiver", "Null PDU");
                 break;
             case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                 Log.i("SmsSentReceiver", "Radio off");
                 break;
          }
       }   
    }
}, new IntentFilter(SENT));

SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage("+xxxxxxx", null, "Hello", sentPI, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` instead of `0` in flag for `getBroadcast()`.

Comment: Also `send.putExtras(bundle);` should be `sendintent.putExtras(bundle);` ? and what is `SENT` intent? Is it `sendintent` in our code as well? Coz this might be the issue you are looking for.

Comment: you're right, I wrote it wrong :) (when copy/paste) but problem not solved

Comment: what is you use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` instead of `0` in flag for getBroadcast?

Comment: oow thank you when i change > PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT